# Maven is looking for dependencies in all the wrong place (for certain things)

Tags: java, maven

I am in the process of converting an existing ANT project to Maven.
I managed to resolve most of the jars, but I am having some difficulties with the following.

I am trying to understand why Maven would look for transitive dependencies for these libraries in the same namespace as the artifact that depends on it.

Here's a sample of the error when I run the application inside of IntelliJ.

> [19 Aug 2020 16:08:12,619] [main] [StandardJarScanner] WARN Failed to
> scan [file:
> .m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar]
> from classloader hierarchy -
> org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog.warn(JuliLog.java:146)
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> .m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
> (No such file or directory)

In fact, [jaxb-runtime 2.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1) does depend on the libraries reported below; but I'm not sure why it would look for FastInfoset inside of `org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1`. I'm having the same issue with `mail-1.4.jar`. No other dependencies are giving me this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

- javax.mail.mail.1.4

  - activation.jar
- org.glassfish.jaxb.jaxb-runtime.2.3.1

  - jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
  - txw2-2.3.1.jar
  - istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
  - stax-ex-1.8.jar
  - FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
  - javax-activation-api-1.2.0.jar

Comment: what group did you set for jaxb-runtime? can you share your pom?

Comment: I'm using the one from org.glassfish.jaxb. Unfortunately I am not able share my pom file. I'm just not sure why it would look for its dependencies within the org.glassfish.jaxb group vs referencing the proper namespace. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem right now, had you finally found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the exact same issue.

To solve it, the only solution I found was to explicitly add the dependency to glassfish.jaxb.runtime in my project.

*In IntelliJ:*

*Right click on project->Open Module Settings*

*Libraries*

*'+'->From Maven*

*Type jaxb-runtime then choose the version for which the dependency is being required (here 2.3.1).*

*Apply and you should be good.*